# buscar palabra en directorio

Tags: c#, windows

Necesito en C# Forms, recorrer todos los archivos que hay en una carpeta y buscar una palabra y que el programa me diga el nombre de los archivos en los que puedo encontrar esta palabraítulo ##faz. }

el codigo que tengo es

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace viernes16
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ruta = @"" + txtruta.Text; //Escribir ruta
            string texto = txtfiltro.Text; //Escribir texto a buscar

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"" + ruta);
            List<string> encontrados = new List<string>();

            foreach (string File in Directory.GetFiles(ruta, texto))
            {

                if (File.ReadAllText(File, Encoding.Default).ToUpper().Contains(texto.ToUpper()))
                    MessageBox.Show($"Archivo: {File}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: debes agregar que probaste hasta ahora, y donde estas trabado

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo actual a la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

con `Directory.GetFiles(directorio, patron)`, puedes lograr lo que estas buscando este se encuentra dentro de `System.IO`;

ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles("c://", "*i*.*");
            foreach (string archivo in archivos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(archivo);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

patrón no acepta `regex`, solo los comodines * y ?